# Is 今天的锻炼打卡了 correct usage of the phrase 打卡?

Tags: usage

I've asked a question about the phrase 打卡 before.

Today I was moving house and I walked in and out of the house with big boxes and bags for 3 solid hours.

When I was finally done I thought to myself ''That's my exercise done for the day.'' but I said it to myself in Chinese and this is what I said : ''今天的锻炼打卡了''.

Is this usage correct ?

Comment: You can say it that way. To me, it sounds a bit humorous. But it needs some explanation about your context(as you put in this question).

Comment: Can be correct, to me.

Answer (score 3):

打卡 (punch-in) originally meant "to record the time your present at your workplace" and it is an obligation

Later, people borrowed this term to describe "visiting a place that's considered a must-see place by the general public." As if it was an obligation like you are obligated to go to your workplace

For example, if you go to Paris, Eiffel Tower is a must-see, according to the general public. When you actually get there, you would say "来埃菲尔铁塔打卡了" (I have punched in at The Eiffel Tower) as if you have completed an obligation.

> 今天的锻炼打卡了

I don't think it is a correct usage of 打卡 in this sense of 'completed an obligation' - The general public doesn't consider exercise a must-try thing

Typically we 打卡 at must-see places or at places that you can try must-try things.

Example:

来到兰州自然要去兰州拉面店打卡了 (When you come to Lanzhou, you have to go to the Lanzhou Ramen shop to check-in)

> ' That's my exercise done for the day.'

這是今天份的锻炼了

Comment: It doesn't have to be an obligation for the general public. Fitness or learning is an obligation or a goal for the person doing it. There are many apps/websites offering the ability to 每日打卡 (record that you did x thing each day, e.g. you ran 10 km or listened to 30 minutes of English today).